# NPM equivalent for "npm:@user/package-name" version in package.json?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I saw this in a `package.json` file:

```
"react-native-wheel-picker": "npm:@gregfrench/react-native-wheel-picker",
```

That doesn't match the tarball, http, or git [dependency formats documented in the NPM docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies). Looks like it's a `yarn` convention, because running `yarn` installed that dependency without complaints from the `start` script (which otherwise would complain `warn Package react-native-wheel-picker has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: Cannot find module 'react-native-wheel-picker/package.json'`).

What does that "version" string mean, why not use "@gregfrench/react-native-wheel-picker" directly, and what would be the `package.json` equivalent that would allow `npm` to function correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The npm compatible dependency specification would look like following:

`"@gregfrench/react-native-wheel-picker": "<version>"`

As I see on npmjs.com the latest version for `@gregfrench/react-native-wheel-picker` is `1.2.3` so if the latest version is needed than following should be in the `package.json`:

`"@gregfrench/react-native-wheel-picker": "1.2.3"`

If you don't want to have an exact version there are some possibilities like using `^`,`~`, `>=`.. characters with the version string. These possibilities are [documented here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies).